# Twitter connect in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter

Excuse me.

I am using rails 2.3.8 and RESTFul Authentication.

I need to connect to my site through twitter credentials. So I need a button which connect with twitter and then redirect to action.

In action I must create a new user or update twitter_id.

Please I need help. How can I connect via twitter? I need a tutorial or advice.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you use the OmniAuth gem which provides twitter authentication. You can install it using `gem install omniauth` and easily integrate it into your Rails app. You can find the documentation [here](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/wiki).

While working with omniauth you might want to have a look at the [Twitter OAuth FAQ](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/oauth_faq) and [create a new app](http://dev.twitter.com/apps/new) to get your twitter credentials.

Comment: thanks. I am reading this tutorial http://blog.dhavalparikh.co.in/2009/06/step-by-step-twitter-oauth-integration-with-rails/ However when the app must redirect to action create twitter redirect to https://twitter.com/oauth/authorize with a code. I post this question now. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Also check out great Ryans screencasts
[1](http://railscasts.com/episodes/241-simple-omniauth),
[2](http://railscasts.com/episodes/235-omniauth-part-1),
[3](http://railscasts.com/episodes/236-omniauth-part-2),